# Large rock obstructing addition

Tags: basement, foundation, rock, addition

I potentially have the problem of building an addition to a house where the bedrock comes up alongside the house. So, basically there is a large rock formation obstructing the construction of the basement for the addition.

What are the options? I assume the normal procedure is to blast the rock, but since it is near the house, is it feasible to do blasting?

Comment: you should really be talking to someone that can visit the building site.

Answer (score 1):

Bedrock - skip the basement, have the best foundation money can't buy. Remove the dirt, drill holes for pins to anchor your footings to the rock, build a house on it - or a skyscraper.

If you have more of a "fight with nature, rather than work with nature" approach, it's going to be harder, more expensive, and more tedious, and exactly what options you have and how dreadful they will be will depend on the rock - granite is rather more difficult than schist, for a couple typical NE USA bedrocks.

Comment: If it's merely a glacial erratic and not bedrock, you either do the same if it's big enough, or you dig a bigger hole and roll it into the hole..

Comment: Just don't roll it into your neighbors yard unless you are sure nobody's home. ;-)